# How do I properly set up the Cassandra client in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, cassandra, cassandra-2.1

Right now, I'm running a docker with Cassandra on it. I have a javascript file that sits outside the docker that needs to connect to Cassandra. I've found a node package that interfaces w/ JS, called `cassandra-driver`. However, with the following code:

```
var cassandra = require('cassandra-driver');
var PlainTextAuthProvider = cassandra.auth.PlainTextAuthProvider;
const client = new cassandra.Client({
    contactPoints: ['127.0.0.1:9042'],
    localDataCenter: '127.0.0.1',
    keyspace: 'wasabi_experiments',
    authProvider: new PlainTextAuthProvider('cassandra', 'cassandra')
});
```

I get

```
(node:17836) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): NoHostAvailableError: All host(s) tried for query failed. First host tried, 127.0.0.1:9042: ArgumentError: localDataCenter was configured as '127.0.0.1', but only found hosts in data centers: [datacenter1]. See innerErrors.
(node:17836) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 2): NoHostAvailableError: All host(s) tried for query failed. First host tried, 127.0.0.1:9042: ArgumentError: localDataCenter was configured as '127.0.0.1', but only found hosts in data centers: [datacenter1]. See innerErrors.
```

How can I get this to work?

Answer (score 4):

Your problem is that you're using the `127.0.0.1` as value for `localDataCenter` parameter, but it should be set not to the address of the machine, but to the name of the Cassandra data center - in your case this is `datacenter1`. Change the value of that parameter to `datacenter1`, and it will start to work.

It would be:

```js
const { Client, auth } = require('cassandra-driver');
const client = new cassandra.Client({
    contactPoints: ['127.0.0.1:9042'],
    localDataCenter: 'datacenter1', // here is the change required
    keyspace: 'wasabi_experiments',
    authProvider: new auth.PlainTextAuthProvider('cassandra', 'cassandra')
});

client.connect();
```

P.S. I recommend to read [documentation for Node.js driver](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/nodejs-driver/4.1/index.html), and also ["Developing applications with DataStax drivers" guide](https://docs.datastax.com/en/devapp/doc/devapp/aboutDrivers.html).

Comment: thanks; but now I'm getting `Error: Cannot find module 'thrift'`

Comment: I think that it could be something with installation - unfortunately I'm not Node.js guy. Can you ask at https://community.datastax.com/ ?

Answer (score 0):

try first with a Cassandra client, ensure Cassandra is working properly and you can access it. After that try with the code.
Also you can try to access the 127.0.0.1:9042 using telnet or netcat to see if the port is open and listening. You can use netstat too for this task.

Comment: his connection works - he simply didn't pass correct parameters.